# SAPUI5 get the current screen size

Tags: sapui5, screen-size

At a specific point of my application I need to determine the current [screen size](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ScreenSize/properties) (Desktop or Tablet). At least I would need the screen width but the sap.m.ScreenSize would be better.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sizeChanged(mParams) {
    switch(mParams.name) {
        case "Phone":
            // Do what is needed for a little screen
            break;
        case "Tablet":
            // Do what is needed for a medium sized screen
            break;
        case "Desktop":
            // Do what is needed for a large screen
    }
}

// Register an event handler to changes of the screen size
sap.ui.Device.media.attachHandler(sizeChanged, null, 
sap.ui.Device.media.RANGESETS.SAP_STANDARD);
// Do some initialization work based on the current size

sizeChanged(sap.ui.Device.media.getCurrentRange(sap.ui.Device.media.RANGESETS.SAP_STANDARD));
```

I got this code from:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/api/sap.ui.Device.media

there u will also get a more detailed description of how it works